# Percentage change in values in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the df I am using:

```
              Date Country      City Specie count min max median variance
27  2020-03-25      IN     Delhi   pm25   797   6 192     92 12116.60
159 2020-03-25      IN   Chennai   pm25    96  27  89     57  1928.38
223 2020-03-25      IN    Mumbai   pm25   285  12 163     90  6275.41
412 2020-03-25      IN Bengaluru   pm25   179  25 145     73  4890.82
419 2020-03-25      IN   Kolkata   pm25   260   6 168    129 10637.10
10  2020-04-10      IN     Delhi   pm25   835   2 393    137 24542.30
132 2020-04-10      IN   Chennai   pm25    87   5 642     53 87856.50
298 2020-04-10      IN    Mumbai   pm25   168   1 125     90  5025.35
358 2020-04-10      IN Bengaluru   pm25   159  21 834     56 57091.10
444 2020-04-10      IN   Kolkata   pm25   219   4 109     64  2176.61
```

I want to calculate the percentage change between 'median' values of the data frame. For that I have used the following code:

```
    pct_change_pm25 <- day %>%
  arrange(City, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = -diff(median) / median[-1] * 100)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incorrect size (1) at position 2, expecting : 10
```

The number of rows that mutate is creating is 9 and is not matching with the number of rows in the df.
 I have followed this post on stackoverflow:
[Calculate Percentage Change in R using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196552/calculate-percentage-change-in-r-using-dplyr)

But, unfortunately id didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `diff` returns vector of length 1 less than the original vector, append an `NA` at the start of the calculation. Also probably you want to do this for each `City` separately,hence grouping by city.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(City) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = c(NA, -diff(median) / median[-1] * 100))
```

Another way to do the same calculation is using `lag`

```
df %>%
  arrange(City) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (lag(median) - median)/median * 100)


#  Date       Country City      Specie count   min   max median variance pct_change
#   <fct>      <fct>   <fct>     <fct>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>    <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 2020-03-25 IN      Bengaluru pm25     179    25   145     73    4891.      NA   
# 2 2020-04-10 IN      Bengaluru pm25     159    21   834     56   57091.      30.4 
# 3 2020-03-25 IN      Chennai   pm25      96    27    89     57    1928.      NA   
# 4 2020-04-10 IN      Chennai   pm25      87     5   642     53   87856.       7.55
# 5 2020-03-25 IN      Delhi     pm25     797     6   192     92   12117.      NA   
# 6 2020-04-10 IN      Delhi     pm25     835     2   393    137   24542.     -32.8 
# 7 2020-03-25 IN      Kolkata   pm25     260     6   168    129   10637.      NA   
# 8 2020-04-10 IN      Kolkata   pm25     219     4   109     64    2177.     102.  
# 9 2020-03-25 IN      Mumbai    pm25     285    12   163     90    6275.      NA   
#10 2020-04-10 IN      Mumbai    pm25     168     1   125     90    5025.       0
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, pct_change := (shift(median) - median)/median * 100, City]
```