# Calculating Percent Changes in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I made this data frame in R:

```
library(dplyr)

year = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020")

var = rnorm(11,100, 11)

df = data.frame(year, var)
```

I would like to create a new variable that looks in the percent change (in "var") between each pair of consecutive rows. I tried to follow the answer provided in this link over here: [Percentage change in values in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169183/percentage-change-in-values-in-r)

```
df %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(pct_change = (lag(var) - var)/var * 100)
```

This keeps giving me an NA result:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   year [11]
   year    var pct_change
   <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2010  111.          NA
 2 2011   99.6         NA
 3 2012  102.          NA
 4 2013   87.2         NA
 5 2014   99.3         NA
 6 2015  103.          NA
 7 2016  110.          NA
 8 2017  109.          NA
 9 2018   79.8         NA
10 2019  113.          NA
11 2020  123.          NA
```

Could someone please show me how to resolve this problem?

E.g. `(99.6 - 11/ 111)*100 , (102 - 99.6/99.6)*100,` etc.

Thank you!

Comment: That is because you are grouping by year and there is only one data point in each year. So lag of it is NA

Comment: Thank you! Should I just replace it with this? df %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(pct_change = (lag(var) - var)/var * 100)

Comment: I do not know what you are exactly wishing to accomplish. I

Comment: @  onyambu : please see the updates- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(lagged = lag(var)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = (var - lagged) / lagged) %>% 
  select(-lagged)
```